# Is it possible to trade Seraph weapons with a player that doesn't own the Captain Scarlett DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

[Seraph weapons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lp8Q6Ymk9s) sound like great guns, but I don't have the Captain Scarlett DLC.  On the other side, I've got a few friends who does.  Will I be able to exchange Seraph weapons with them (either by trading or simply dumping it on the floor) ?

[image: Seraph Weapon "Social Actualizer"]

Comment: I remember a message saying I don't have the DLC, I don't remember if I was trying to equip or pick up a seraph weapon though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can - on the Xbox, you have to download a "compatibility pack" that contains all the new DLC's weapons and so forth.  They mention it being required to use the new guns in the DLC, and you don't have to pay for it.

Comment: Sounds really interesting, hope that someone will be able to confirm that asap !  PS: I'm playing with the PC version (if that's of any importance).

Comment: "Seraph weapons sound like great guns" Unfortunately, reality is not always how things sound.

Comment: How sad...  So... I don't need to cry because I don't have the said DLC ?

Comment: @agent86 don't think that's true; the compatability pack was for the Mechromancher's data and such (which is why it doesn't exist on PC)  so you can play *with* people with DLC items, but you still can't own them yourself (otherwise you couldn't play with anyone using Gaige unless you had the DLC yourself)

Comment: @BenBrocka, for every (season pass) DLC released so far, there's been a corresponding compatibility pack for the Xbox, and I thought it had mention of being able to play with them and having support for all the guns.  I'm not really in a position to test though, so I can't confirm (thus the comment(s))

Comment: @agent86: So that support is so that your friends can use their guns, not so you can use them.  I wouldn't be surprised if they did the same thing for BL1, as per my answer.

Comment: I've just tried (PC version): you can see the weapon, loot it, but you cannot equip it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Requires Pirate's Booty

I think that should be prety clear.  If you don't own the DLC, you aren't able to use the weapons that are introduced in that DLC.  This was the same case for Borderlands as well.

Comment: @Anto It's right there in your image.  As to whether you can even pick one up, I'm not sure, but you couldn't in BL1.